# What font is the one used in this picture?

Tags: fonts

[image: What font is this? And what package do I need to add in order to use it?]

What font is this? And what package do I need to add in order to use it?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Do you have, please, the .pdf source of your picture? However there is in math-mode the font CM= computer modern. The text is similar to Garamond.

Comment: Yes, looks like Garamond family or Carlson family

Comment: [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) says: Garamont. Also for me looks like Garamont

Comment: You can see here: https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/garamond/ and peraphs could be also Palatino.

Comment: If you have the PDF, the exact font is in the metadata. If not, you might check identifont.com.

Comment: @Davislor In fact also I have asked the pdf file :-) I'm agree with you.

Comment: I got the book from this url www.math.toronto.edu/scherk/book.pdf

Comment: @RK0000 In that case, you can run `pdffonts` on it.

Comment: According to Acrobat Reader, this book uses some Computer Modern Maths fonts , and also Courier, Garamond (roman, bold, italic), Helvetica, Latin Modern sans & Latin Modern mono.